# How to make a whole website scrollable by dragging

Tags: javascript, event-handling, draggable, drag

I'm using the script below (adapted from https://htmldom.dev/drag-to-scroll/) which enables a website to be scrolled by dragging it. Additionally, I remove the default draggability for links and images via css such that the page can be dragged when the cursor is currently positioned on these elements.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let dragging; const pos = {};

    const onClick = (e) => {
      if(!dragging)
        return;
      
      e.preventDefault(); // somehow does not work: why?
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    };

    const onMouseMove = (e) => {
        dragging = true;
        window.scroll(0, pos.top - (e.clientY - pos.y));
    };

    const onMouseUp = (e) => {
        dragging = false;
        
        e.target.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        e.target.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        e.target.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    };

    const onMouseDown = (e) => {  
        pos.top = window.scrollY;
        pos.y = e.clientY;

        e.target.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        e.target.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        e.target.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
});
```

```css
a, img {
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:200vh; background:lightblue; padding:1em;">
  <h1>Drag to scroll me</h1>
  
  <a href="//stackoverflow.com" style="background:white; padding:1em">Dragging this link should NOT open the website (but does)</a>
</div>
```

#### Problem

Preventing the default action (opening the link) does not work somehow. How can it be canceled in case of dragging?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a bit more complex than I thought, perhaps someone else has a better one. It requires an additional global function `preventClick` which prevents the event default and propagation.

The rest of the code looks like this now:

```js
$(() => {
    /*
        require 'preventClick()';
    */

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // $
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const
        $body = $('body'),
        $head = $('head')
    ;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // var
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const
        pos = {}
    ;
    let
        clone
    ;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ()
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const
        //------------------------------------------
        onMouseMove = (e) => {
        //------------------------------------------
            window.scroll(0, pos.top - (e.originalEvent.clientY - pos.y));
        },
        //------------------------------------------
        onMouseUp = function(e){
        //------------------------------------------
            $body.css('cursor', 'grab');

            $(this)
                .off('mousemove', null, onMouseMove)
                .off('mouseup', null, onMouseUp)
            ;
        }
    ;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Events
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $(document)
        //------------------------------------------
        .mousedown(function(e){
        //------------------------------------------
            $body.css('cursor', 'grabbing');

            pos.top = window.scrollY;
            pos.y = e.originalEvent.clientY;

            $(this)
                .one('dragstart', function(e){
                    clone = $(e.target).clone(true);
                    
                    $(e.target)
                        .attr('onclick', 'preventClick(event)')
                        .one('click', function(e){    
                            $(this).attr('onclick', clone.attr('onclick') || '');
                        })
                    ;
                })
                .mousemove(onMouseMove)
                .mouseup(onMouseUp)
            ;
        })
    ;
    $body
        //------------------------------------------
        .css('cursor', 'grab')
        //------------------------------------------
    ;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // >>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $head.append(`<style>
        a, img {
            user-drag: none;
            -webkit-user-drag: none;
        }
    </style>`);

});
```